# Soft contributions in user dashboard

Tags: contributions, dashboard, user-dashboard, soft-credit

qq re soft credits: on a supporter's dashboard, he/she sees the full contribution amount instead of just the soft credit assigned to them (e.g. if a company sends us a check for $1,000 for donations from 10 of their employees of $100 a piece); I'd think the user should see $100 on the dashboard under "contributions made in your honor" ... no? Is this a bug or works as designed?